# Google Cloud Storage URL signing with target credentials on Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, acl

The ACL after uploading an object to Google Cloud Storage is overwritten each time.

I'm creating `BlobInfo` with preset ACL, so that the uploaded object have to be public read:

```
 String blobId = "PUBLIC/1";
 com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo info = com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo.newBuilder(RuntimeConfig.USERDATA_BUCKET_NAME, blobId)
                .setContentType(mimetype)
                .setMetadata(metadata)
                .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER)))) // <-- HERE
                .build();
```

After this I'm signing the URL, like this:

```
URL signedUrl = storage.signUrl(info, 30,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                    Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(com.google.cloud.storage.HttpMethod.valueOf("PUT")),
                    Storage.SignUrlOption.withContentType());
```

Then, I'm uploading the file from the web and this works fine, with only one problem - there is no ACL with public read.

Of course, I can change the ACL after the upload is done, like this:

```
storage.createAcl(info.getBlobId(), (Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER)));
```

But is there a way to set it directly within the signed URL, without an additional trigger from the web after having successfully uploaded it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### [Signed URLs vs ACLs ( aka. Access Control Lists)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/)

**Access Control Lists (ACLs)** and **Signed URLs (query string authentication)** are **not** the same thing.

While they both provide control of who has access to your Cloud Storage buckets and objects as well as as what level of access they have, **ACLs grant read or write access to users for individual buckets or objects**. In most instances, Cloud IAM permissions are used over ACLs since the latter are only used when fine-grained control over individual objects is needed.

On the other hand, **Signed URLs provide time-limited read or write access to an object through a generated URL**. Anyone who has this URL will have access to the object for a certain duration of time that is specified.

Therefore, I'm not aware of any way to implement ACLs directly within Signed URLs to answer your question.

---

### Managing your ACLs

From [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists#defaultobjects):

> To avoid **setting ACLs every time you create a new object**, you can **set a default object ACL on a bucket**. After you do this, every new object that is added to that bucket that does not explicitly have an ACL applied to it will have the default applied to it.

---

**Changing the default object ACL**

The following sample adds a default object ACL to a bucket:

```
Acl acl = storage.createDefaultAcl(bucketName, Acl.of(User.ofAllAuthenticatedUsers(), Role.READER));
```

The following sample deletes a default object ACL from a bucket:

```
boolean deleted = storage.deleteDefaultAcl(bucketName, User.ofAllAuthenticatedUsers());
if (deleted) {
  // the acl entry was deleted
} else {
  // the acl entry was not found
}
```

---

### Propagation Details

If you **change the default object ACL for a bucket**, the change may take time to propagate, and new objects created in the bucket may still get the old default object ACL for a short period of time. In order to make sure that new objects created in the bucket get the updated default object ACL, you should **wait at least 30 seconds between changing the default object ACL and creating new objects**.